# Unable to pass all conditions on codechef problem TREE2

Tags: java, arrays, logic

please can someone check and tell why this code is unable to pass the 80% condition.

This problem is presented on the CodeChef with the problem code TREE2. It is problem in the beginner section.

There are 2 tasks. with the following code I am able to pass the task of 20%, but I am unable to pass the second task which consists of 80%.

Please look into it and suggest what went wrong.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Codechef
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        int t,n,h;
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        t=s.nextInt();
        while(t-- > 0)
        {   h=0;
            n=s.nextInt();
            int [] arr=new int [n];
            
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                arr[i]=s.nextInt();
            Arrays.sort(arr);
            
            while(true)
            {
                if(arr[n-1]==0)
                break;
                h++;
                if(arr[0]==arr[n-1])
                    break;
                    
                for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
                {
                    if(arr[i]!=arr[n-1])
                    {
                        for(int j=i;j<n;j++)
                            arr[j]=arr[i];
                        break;
                    }
                }
                
            }
            System.out.println(h);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome. I believe it would not be fair if we would give you help in a competition. If you need any general help related to programming, or a particular issue, then feel free to come back. Some things that come to my mind when dealing with these is: running out of time, memory or overflowing a variable.

Answer (score 0):

its cause of time complexity.
you are using 4 loops.
that results in n raise to 4 time complexity.
try to solve using only one loop or without loop.
for hint go through SET concept